# ld+json validator Ajv that examines multiple items in an array if necessary

Tags: node.js, json, json-ld, ajv

I'm now trying to create the webpage that checks the syntax validation of ld+json. If a user give a url from the client side, it will be sent to the server side where the program gets its  and validate its syntax using ajv package of npm.

As an example, I made a FAQ schema to validate an Json file.

```js
const schemaF = {
  type:"object",
  properties:{
    "@context":{type: "string"},
    "@type":{type:"string"},
    "@mainEntity": {
      type:"array",
      items:[{
        type: "object",
        properties:{
          "@type":{type: "string"},
          "name":{type: "string"},
          "acceptedAnswer": {
            type: "object",
            properties:{
              "@type": {type:"string"},
              "text": {type: "string"}
            }
          }
        },
        required: ["acceptedAnswer", "@type"],
      }]
    }
  },
  required: ["@context", "@type", "mainEntity"]
}
```

This schema works properly only when there are only one question and answer set; in the code above, when there is only one item in the array. This makes sense given the code I wrote.

```js
const sample2 = {
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "FAQPage",
  "mainEntity": [{
    "@type": "Question",
    "name": "What is the return policy?",
    "acceptedAnswer": {
      "@type": "Answer",
      "text": "<p>Most unopened items in new condition and returned within <b>90 days</b> will receive a refund or exchange. Some items have a modified return policy noted on the receipt or packing slip. Items that are opened or damaged or do not have a receipt may be denied a refund or exchange. Items purchased online or in-store may be returned to any store.</p><p>Online purchases may be returned via a major parcel carrier. <a href=http://example.com/returns> Click here </a> to initiate a return.</p>"
    }
    }
 ]
}
```

However, it is most likely that there are more than two question and answer pairs (items).

Here is the question;
Is it possible to create the schema to check multiple items' format in @mainEntity items(array) with ajv schema validator? I would like to accept and check multiple items as well as one item like above.
Thank you.

Comment: I don't know much about ajv, but it's certainly possible with [joi](https://joi.dev/)